# How to port a large number of users database records into a history storage after the user has been deleted?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm currently using SQL server and Entity Framework. We have a large database which consists of many additional tables linked via relationships. There are at least 15 tables that have a relationship with the main table "Users".

eg.
Users

- UsersAddress
- UserProfile
- UserType
- Products
- Purchases
- ... another 10 or so

Now if a user wants to be removed from the system we require to still keep transaction data etc due to taxation reasons and a host of other internal reasons. If a user deletes their account then all other tables data cascade and are lost. So we require to remove the users information but store it in another set of tables.

We were thinking of creating duplicate tables with a starting table name of "Deleted". eg DeletedUsers -> DeletedUserAddress etc..

But it seems odd to pull a record by id, new up a Model, send it to the deleted table, pull the next table data, new up a Model, store it to the deleted table and so on. Then at the end delete the main user table record and all records are cascaded and removed from the db.

Can anyone suggest a more efficient way of storing history data.

I could see that if i tried

```
//GET THE USER
UsersTableModel user = await db.Users.SingleOrDefault(x => x.id == 1234);

//AIM TO STORE
db.DeletedUsers.Add(user);
```

would not work, i would need to completely new up a DeletedUsers model and Add.

Is there a simpler way?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope it may help you!

There are 15 tables have a relationship with the User table. So if you delete the user from User table then related data in 15 tables also will be deleted (cascade). So It's difficult/NoLogic to history the 15 tables data.

**Solution:** Instead of deleting the user from the user table, Just hold the record with one column like ***IsDeleted*** in the User table. Add one new column to the user table named as **IsDeleted** and update it with 0(active),1(deleted).

Then while fetching User records, Transaction details you should add the filter (where clause) based on your needs. like following,

```
db.Users.Where(x=>x.IsDeleted==0) // to fetch users and details except deleted users
db.Users.Where(x=>x.IsDeleted==1) // to fetch deleted users and details
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a soft delete option where you can add one more column in your table as 'isDeleted'='0' or '1' and you can filter it based on isDeleted option ...that way you would be able to preserve your records